# Flex full height page with scroll

Tags: css, flexbox

I need this kind of layout in flex to be full height

[image]

What I need that red background has scroll based on content inside, if there is more content  to stay same size just to have scroll? Is this possible with flex?

This is what i have for now

```
<style>
  .content {
    display: flex;    

  .content-left {
    display: flex;
    width: 512px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 56px;    

  .content-header {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    
      small {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }    
    }
  }
    
  .content-right {
    display: flex;
    width: 928px;
  }
</style>
```

```
<header>TEST<header>
<div class="container">
  <section class="content">
    <aside class="content-left">
      <div class="content-header">
        <small></small>
        <h1>
         TITLE
        </h1>
      </div>
      <section class="content-body">

      </section>
      <section class="content-footer">
       
      </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="content-right">
     
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the result you are looking for : https://codepen.io/camillewemajin/pen/wveZGQR ?

If so you're not so far, just add :

```
  .content-body{
    background-color:yellow;
    height:200px ;
    max-height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid system quite well for such designs.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.item1, .item3, .item2 div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">header</div>
  <div class="item2">
    <div class="green">title</div>
    <div class="red">image or red something</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">aside aside aside aside aside aside aside aside aside aside aside aside</div>  
</div>
```